# Python socket server error

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, python-2.7

I am getting some errors upon data being sent to the server. I am very new with Python Sockets and this is a simple script. Here it is

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('ip', 53863)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 284, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 310, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 638, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "serv.pyz", line 9, in handle
    print(self.client_address + ' : ' + self.data)
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple
```

Serv.pyz (I know, it should be .py)

```
import SocketServer


class SEER(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):

def handle(self):
    while 1:
        self.data = self.request.recv(9000)
        print(self.client_address + ' : ' + self.data)
server = SocketServer.TCPServer(('', 4857), SEER)
server.serve_forever()
```

Also, how could I add a Client class to store things like Client.room_id or Client.joinRoom(1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.client_address` is tuple, you should use `self.client_address[0]` instead like [this](http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html#socketserver-udpserver-example).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the print function to:

```
    print(str(self.client_address) + ' : ' + str(self.data))
```

According to the error, one of the variables is a tuple so this should convert it to a string.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is as given by the traceback:

```
print(self.client_address + ' : ' + self.data)
```

self.client_address is a tuple. You want (in this case) self.client_address[0]
Either that or print them out on separate lines

Answer (score 0):

`self.client_address` is a tuple, not a string! So you'll need to print the str() of it.

`SEER` is your client class, so create `self.room_id`, etc., to store client state and implement methods.

TCP is also a streaming protocol, so you'll need to implement a message protocol on top of it to be sure you have a complete message.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9968240/235698) for an example.