# How do you send numbers over python sockets?

Tags: python, sockets

I try to send padded numbers of 4 characters, but when I send

```
# sender
number = str(2).zfill(4)
sending_socket.send(number)



# receiver      
msg = receiving_socket.recv(4)
print msg
```

The msg printed comes out to be 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have something you aren't showing us wrong:

```
# sender
>>> from socket import *
>>> s=socket()
>>> s.connect(('localhost',8000))
>>> number=str(2).zfill(4)
>>> s.send(number)

# receiver
>>> from socket import *
>>> s=socket()
>>> s.bind(('',8000))
>>> s.listen(1)
>>> c,a=s.accept()
>>> c.recv(4)
'0002'
```

Comment: True. I send 1 over and it works, and then 2 comes out to be 11. Is it a buffer problem?

Comment: TCP is a streaming protocol so it has no message boundaries.  Also `send` and `recv` need their return values checked because they may not send or receive the amount requested.  You have to design a protocol that takes this into account, sending the size of the message in the data, for example.

Comment: See another answer of mine for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9968240/235698.  Update your question with an example that demonstrates the problem and I can give a better answer.

Comment: Got it, I'm going to use a sentinel byte. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome!  If all you are sending is 4-byte formatted numbers, just making sure your messages are exactly 4 bytes will work as a protocol also.